# How to load a custom js script in YUI 3

Tags: javascript, load, yui3

I am a newbie to web development but have been playing around with YUI for a few months now. Can anyone let me know how to load a custom "js" script in YUI 3?

I want to use the "contentflow" carousel in YUI 3. For this i need to include the [contentflow.js](http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/) within the "YUI.use()" so that I can access the methods.

Answer (score 1):

To add a module (so that YUI recognises it) you need to add it to the configuration. There are three ways of doing this.

1. Using `YUI_config = {};` sets a global configuration object for all `YUI().use`
2. Using `YUI.GlobalConfig = {};` sets a global configuration object for all `YUI().use`
3. Using `YUI({}).use(...;` sets a local configuration object for this `YUI().use`

In the config object you need to configure the module to be understood in your use.

```
{
    filter : "raw",
    modules : {
        "contentFlow" : {
            fullpath : "path/to/contentFlow.js"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
YUI().use("contentFlow", function (Y) {
    //content flow available here 
});
```

However I would recommend using the `YUI.add` method in the content flow JavaScript to expose the content flow "class". So in `contentFlow.js`, I would wrap the following:

```
YUI.add("contentFlow", function (Y) {
    //contentFlow.js contents goes here...         
    ...
    //end of file
    Y.ContentFlow = ContentFlow;
}, '', {});
```

Then you can:

```
YUI().use("contentFlow", function (Y) {
    var cf = new Y.ContentFlow({...}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Load a single JavaScript resource.
Y.Get.js('http://example.com/file.js', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        Y.log('Error loading JS: ' + err[0].error, 'error');
        return;
    }

    Y.log('file.js loaded successfully!');
});
```

Source: https://clarle.github.io/yui3/yui/docs/get/